# How to insert radio button true or false to database ms.access in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

i want if i checked radiobutton1 then field status(data type: yes/no, format: true/false) in database ms.access is true(checked), if i checked radiobutton2 then field status(data type: yes/no, format: true/false) in database ms.access is false(unchecked).

my script is:

```
dim s as boolean
if radiobutton1.checked = true then
s = true
elseif radiobutton2.checked = true then
s = false
end if

                cmd = New OleDbCommand("Insert into table_petugas (name,status) Values ('" & txtname.Text & "','" & status & "' )", conn)
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                MsgBox("Data Saved!", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "PERHATIAN!")
```

but the script is error, saying: "data type mismatch in criteria expression"
help me, please..
sorry for my bad language..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a parameterized query

```
cmd = New OleDbCommand("Insert into table_petugas (name,status) Values (?,?)", conn)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", txtname.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", s) 
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

This approach pass the work to correctly define the values required by your database fields  to the framework code that create a boolean parameter and update your field.

Of course this will avoid also any possible Sql Injection scenario

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is your "status" variable which is not present on the code?

```
dim s as boolean
if radiobutton1.checked = true then
s = true
elseif radiobutton2.checked = true then
s = false
end if

cmd = New OleDbCommand("Insert into table_petugas (name,status) Values ('" & txtname.Text & "','" & s & "' )", conn)
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
MsgBox("Data Saved!", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "PERHATIAN!")
```